# Compare input to answer, regardless of order

Tags: python, input

I want to evaluate people's input answers by comparing it to the correct answer

Right now I have

```
stimuli_words = ["tree","bird","cake","ocean","dance","statistics","headphone", "red","duck"]
chosen_stimuli = stimuli_words[0:2]

correct_answer = ''.join(chosen_stimuli)

if(''.join(key_resp.keys).upper() == correct_answer.upper()):
   print('correct')
```

Using this code, only when people are entering the words in the exact order they are presented will receive "correct" feedback. I want the program to be able to evaluate people's input regardless of the order of input, how do I do this?

This code is from a task where people read a list of words then recall. They will type out words through "key_resp" (this is a keyboard component in PsychoPy). key_resp.keys inputs are letters rather than words, so sorting would result in sorting the letters. Even though I can sort the answer part as follows, but I still cannot equivalent the two sides. My next step is to create feedback that evaluate how many words did the person recalled correctly so I eventually want the program to go through the answer list and the key_response list and tell me how many are a match.

```
correct_answer =''.join(sorted(chosen_stim)).upper()
```

Comment: Can you make it clear which bit of this is the user input?

Comment: sort them both.

Comment: Sorting would only work if ALL of the answers are correct, depending on what exactly you wan them to sort by.

Comment: What, exactly is key_resp? Can we see where it is defined?

Comment: That's no more clear. What does `key_resp.keys` look like when you print it?

Comment: `if sorted(map(upper, key_resp.keys)) == sorted(map(upper, chosen_stimuli)):`

Comment: I got this error "NameError: name 'upper' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex function
[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall). This will find all non-overlapping matches.

Example code:

```
regex = re.compile('|'.join(stimuli_words), re.IGNORECASE)
matches = regex.findall(''.join(key_resp.keys))
# then compare matches items with chosen_stimuli items
```